# Retrieving and removing an object from an NSMutableDictionary in one go

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Is there a way to retrieve and remove an object from an NSMutableDictionary in one go? A method that would collapse the following:

```
id myObject = [myMutableDict objectForKey:@"myKey"]

if(myObject)
{
    [myMutableDict removeObjectForKey:@"myKey"];

    ...my code...
}
```

in to:

```
id myObject = [myMutableDict retrieveAndRemoveObjectForKey:@"myKey"];

if (myObject)
{
    ...my code...
}
```

I'm not running in to any bottlenecks or anything and I haven't profiled anything, but it just makes sense to have a method for removing an object from a mutable dictionary and returning it in one go, so that the dictionary doesn't end up finding "myObject" twice (I know I shouldn't make any assumptions about how NSMutableDictionary works internally).

Comment: "makes sense"?  No it doesn't.  I haven't seen such methods in any collection classes in any other language runtimes.  If you want to write one yourself, however, then creating a category is the way to proceed.

Comment: "I haven't seen such methods in any collection classes in any other language runtimes." that's hardly an argument for it making sense or not. In other languages you can find an element, get an iterator, and then remove the object with the iterator in constant time. Here, NSMutableDictionary would probably have to find "myObject" twice internally, once in each method call, so a method that does both would make perfect sense. Anyways, if there isn't anything built-in then I guess the answer is no.

Comment: At least there is such method in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop

Comment: @Droppy what about pop ? in a stack it's common to pop (retrieve and remove) the last element... why not in a dictionnary? I kinda get the need. :)

Comment: Yup, so there's one.  But it's certainly not common, and the need for it doesn't just "make sense", especially given dictionaries are geared towards fast look-up anyway.

Comment: It could be simply handy and even offer some performance improvement in case of tree-based dictionaries.

Comment: @Droopy There are more than one, Python was just one example. It doesn't matter if dictionaries are geared towards fast lookup, it's still having to look-up twice for absolutely no reason at all, and doing a needless lookup even if it is fast doesn't make sense. It's the opposite of premature optimisation.

Comment: @Rajveer actually optimising compiler can produce code with single lookup for you.. you have no guarantee though

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Hopefully it will as that's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a category to `NSMutableDictionary` and add the function:

```
-(id) retrieveAndRemoveObjectForKey:(NSString*)key {
     id myObject = [self objectForKey:@"myKey"];

     if(myObject)
     {
         [self removeObjectForKey:@"myKey"];
     }

     return myObject;
}
```

if you have a bad access means that you need to retain `myObject`

Comment: That isn't a category as it's referencing a variable called `myMutableDict`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, write a category on NSMutablArray :

NSMutableArray+Pop.h

```
@interface NSMutableArray (pop)

-(id) popObjectForKey:(NSString*)key;

@end
```

NSMutableArray+Pop.m

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (pop)

-(id) popObjectForKey:(NSString*)key {
    id result = self[key];
    self[key] = nil;
    return result;
}

@end
```